# Print Json data into html format

Tags: php, json, ajax, zend-framework2

I posted the image in an array from my form using `AJAX`, and in response I received a `JSON` data

I received the below code in my console as response;

```
0"C:\xampp\htdocs\3Dklik\..../1492427792slider_7.jpg"
1"C:\xampp\htdocs\3Dklik\mog/1492427792slider_2.jpg"
2"C:\xampp\htdocs\3Dklik\mo…../public/img/1492427792"
id""
user_id"1"
```

The following is my `AJAX` code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#btnsubmit").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = $('#uploadform').serialize();
            var files = $("#uploadform")[0];
            console.log(files);
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo $this->url('
                upload ');?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: new FormData(files),
                xhr: function() {
                    var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    return myXhr;
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Data Uploaded: " + data);
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("Error");
                },

                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the following is my `PHP` code;

```
public function uploadAction() {
    $request = $this - > getRequest();
    if ($request - > isPost()) {
        $data = array_merge_recursive(
            $request - > getPost() - > toArray(),
            $request - > getFiles() - > toArray()
        );
        // echo'<pre>';print_r($data); 
    }
    $image_array = array_slice($data, 2);
    //print_r($image_array); 
    foreach($image_array as $files) {
        //print_r($files); 
        $file_new_name = round(microtime(true)).$files['name'];
        $destination = "public/img/".$file_new_name;
        $file_name = $files['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($file_name, $destination);
        $data[] = __DIR__.('/../../../../../public/img/').$file_new_name;
    }
    return new JsonModel(array(
        'data' => $data
    ));
}
```

Basically the `JSON` data includes the image path, but I wish to display the image in my `<div>`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can sen the `JSON` format like `validate.php` in you can use;

`echo json_encode(arrayvalue);`

```
$("#btnsubmit").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $('#uploadform').serialize();
    var files = $("#uploadform")[0];
    console.log(files);
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $this->url('
        upload ');?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData(files),
        dataType: 'json',
        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Data Uploaded: " + data);
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                alert(data[i].imgName);
            });
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert("Error");
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: how can i get imgName ?

Comment: you can send the datas                                                                        
   $this->url(' upload '); in  file  array('id' =>1,'imgname' =>'somename');                after you can use json_encode(array);